# Can I let one hand go from a two-handed weapon to use Wrist Razors?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, dark-sun

I'm making a character that comes from a primal, uncivilized wilderness and I thought using Wrist Razors and a Trikal would be cool.

Can I let go of the Trikal (a two-handed weapon) with the hand that has the wrist razor equipped, and make an attack with the wrist razor? Or can I only attack with the Trikal when I have it out?

Answer (score 5):

> Wrist razors do not need to be drawn, nor do they need to be sheathed for the wielder to use the hand the razors are on (Dark Sun Campaign Setting 121).

The other thing we know is that it's a free action to take your hand off your weapon. So you can definitely do what you're talking about, take a hand off your two handed weapon and attack with your wrist razors.

You would not be able to *attack* with the Trikal in this state, but it's a free action to grip it again, so that's no problem.